# How to range query on grouped / faceted result in Solr

Tags: solr, grouping, facet

Considere this sample:

client

a (10 entries)

b (2 entries)

c (8 entries)

I need to count how many clients have a number of entries in a particular range, for instance [0 TO 5] and [6 TO 10], so the result should be:

[0 TO 5] 1

[6 TO 10] 2

I know I have to group or facet by client, but then i don't know how to process that result.

If group by client is it possible to do a range/facet query on numFound?

If a facet by client is it possible to do the same on facet_fields?

I guess no, anyone stuck in the same problem? I prefer to not process the full array in the frontend.

Comment: What does your documents actually look like?